# No matching function for call to conv (armadillo library)

Tags: c++, armadillo

I've some matlab script to translate in C++ so I decided to use the library Armadillo for the linear algebra parts.
But I'm blocked with the `conv()` function. I tried this:

```
hist2=arma::hist(X2,nbins);
arma::vec g (smoothingWindowWidth, 0.0);
int halfWidth = smoothingWindowWidth/2;
for (int i=0; i<smoothingWindowWidth; i++)
{
    int n=i - halfWidth;
    g[i]= exp(-0.5 *((n/((double)halfWidth))*(n/((double) halfWidth))));
}
g=g/(arma::sum(g));
arma::vec hist3= arma::conv(hist2,g,"same");
```

When I try to compile I get the following error: "*no matching function for call to 'conv(arma::uvec&,arma::vec&,int)'*".

`hist2` has been defined previously as an `uvec` using the `hist()` function.
`X2` is a `vec` and `nbins` an `int`.

I'm not sure to understand the error: It's seems that `conv()` doesn't take `vec` or `uvec` as parameters but after checking the Armadillo website it has to.

I tried to convert the `uvec` into `vec` but it didn't change anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "same" is not an int.

Comment: I was so focused on my vectors that I didn't notice the 'int' part.
I don't understand why 'same' would be an int. I try typing "same" as the Documentation did in the example but it still doesn't work. The error is 'no matching function for call to 'conv(arma::uvec&, arma::vec&, const char [5])'

Comment: @RomainMartin - You're probably using an old version of Armadillo, which doesn't have the latest `conv()` function. Remove the previous version and install the [latest](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) version.

Comment: @mtall - The fact is that I already have the latest version 7.600.2 :/
Is it possible that it hasn't been installed correctly? It would be strange as I can use other functionnality without any issue.
Maybe it's because I don't use the C++11 standard?

Comment: In fact I tried the website's example and I get another error: 'undefined reference to 'wrapper_ddot_'. I think that some of the packages needed for Armadillo haven't been installed or linked correctly. I'll look this way.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally the answer was quite simple: `conv()` doesn't allow mixed types so I had to use two `vec` instead of one `vec` and one `uvec`.

I was pretty sure to already have tried this but maybe there was a problem with my installation at this moment.

So I reinstalled Armadillo properly, assuring that both Lapack and BLAS where found by Armadillo.

Then I add: `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` just before `#include<armadillo>`

After doing this, the example of `conv()` given in the documentation worked.

So I modified my code by converting `hist3` into a `vec`:

```
arma::vec hist3=arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(arma::hist(X2,nbbins));
```

Then it worked!